# using 3 variables in the beginning of an IF statement in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a web page that displays all of the accounts. Underneath it, I have the option where they can have the table highlight certain rows depending on the Balance column. My question is if I can create an `if` statement where the first line contains only variables (including the greater than, equal to, etc option).
My original set up is that they would select from a drop down menu if they want `>`, `>=`, `=`, `<=`, or `<` and then the second part is they would put in the amount. I am guessing the `if` statement doesn't like that I have an option for them to select the operator.

Here is the code for the form part of my web page:

```
#form
print("<form action='http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/Bank_ViewAll.py'>")
print("<center>Highlight rows based on balance amounts!</center>")
print("<BR><BR>")
print("<center>Balance:&nbsp;")
print("<select name='option' style=background:#eef9a0> &nbsp; $")
print("<option value='""' style=background:#eef9a0>Choose an  Option</option>")
print("<option value='>' style=background:purple>Greater Than (>)</option>")
print("<option value='>=' style=background:blue>Greater Than or Equal To (>=)</option>")
print("<option value='=' style=background:yellow>Equal To (=)</option>")
print("<option value='<' style=background:orange>Less Than (<)</option>")
print("<option value='<=' style=background:red>Less Than or Equal To (<=)</option>")
print("</select>")
print("<input type='text' size='15' name='bal' style=background-color:#eef9a0>")
print("<br><BR>")
print("<center>")
print("<input type='submit' class='buttonStyle' value='Submit'>&nbsp;&nbsp;")
print("<input type='reset' class='buttonStyle' value='Clear fields'>")
print("</center>")
print("</form>")
#end form
```

And here is the code for my function:

```
import cgi, cgitb, sqlite3
cgitb.enable()
sqlite_file="C:\\Users\\U49228\\Desktop\\Class exercises\\Banking.sqlite"
connect=sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
cursor=connect.cursor()

form=cgi.FieldStorage()
bal=int(form.getvalue('bal'))
opt=form.getvalue('option')

print("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r")
print()

print("<html>")
#Header
print("<head>")
print("<title>View Accounts Functions</title>")
print("</head>")
#body
print("<body bgcolor=#d4f4b0>")
#table
print("<center>")
print("<table border=2>")
print("<th>Acct_No</th>")
print("<th>Name</th>")
print("<th>Balance</th>")
def high_bal():
    cursor.execute("Select * from Banking_Accounts")
    all_rows=cursor.fetchall()
    for row in all_rows:
        accno=row[0]
        cname=row[1]
        amt=int(row[2])
        if amt opt bal:
            print("<tr bgcolor='cornsilk'>")
        else:
            print("<tr>")
        print("<td>"+str(accno)+"</td>")
        print("<td>"+cname+"</td>")
        print("<td>"+str(amt)+"</td>")
        print("</tr>")
    print("</table>")
    print("</center>")
    #end table
    print("<br><BR>")
    print("<center>")
    print("<a href='http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/Bank_Menu.py' style=color:black>Return to Main Menu</a>")
    print("</center>")
    print("</body>")
    print("</html>")
```

I planned on importing my function page. I have tried adding the variables inside the function (`def high_bal(opt,bal)`) as well as trying `onClick` on the submit button and `onSubmit` on the form. I've also tried just making the form redirect to the function page and removing the function name so it is redirecting to a page that will go ahead and do the function without it being called.

Screen shot of my web page design:

[image]
Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html):

```
from operator import gt, ge, eq, le, lt

ops = {'>': gt, '>=':  ge, '=': eq, '<=': le, '<': lt}
```

Now you can do:

```
if ops[opt](amt, bal):
```

Example:

```
>>> opt = '>'
>>> ops[opt](3, 1)
True
>>> ops[opt](3, 10)
False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if amt opt bal:
```

is not a valid python syntax, you can either create a functions for each of the operators like for example

```
operators = {
  '=': lambda x, y : x == y,
  '<': lambda x, y : x < y,
  '>': lambda x, y : x > y,
}

if operators[opt](amt, bal):
```

the other way around (dangerous) is to evaluate the expression:

```
if eval("amt %s bal" % opt):
```